# android hashmap storing object variable within object

Tags: android, android-layout, hash, hashmap, key-value

Hey I am trying to store some values in a `hashmap` to put into a **customized view**.
the problem is when assigning **keys** in the put method of my `hashmap` I get an **error** when I try to get the **key** from a variable within an object that is withing my other object

**here is my code:**

```
     ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     String[] from = new String[] {"fornavn", "starttid", "sluttid"};
     int[] to = new int[] { R.id.Kunde, R.id.StartTime, R.id.EndTime };     

     List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

     for(Appointment a : todayList)     {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            //here is my error I don't know what to put as key??
        map.put("kunde.fornavn", "col_1_item_" + a.kunde.fornavn);
        map.put("starttid", "col_2_item_" + String.valueOf(a.startTime));
        map.put("sluttid", "col_3_item_" + String.valueOf(a.endTime));
        fillMaps.add(map);

     }
     SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.row, from, to);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

logCat:

[image: LogcatInfo]

Comment: are u trying custom list view

Comment: What kind of error do you have? I assume it is `RuntimeException` could you provide trace from LogCat?

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace of your "error".

Comment: I have provided logcat information

Comment: why did you have to post an image? Can't you go through copy/past?

Comment: you have NPE at line 83 in doStuff() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that

```
a.kunde
```

is null